# What does it mean if -1 is returned for .get_device() for torch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-geometric

I am using pytorch geometric to train a graph neural network. The problem that led to this question is the following error:

> RuntimeError: Expected all tensors to be on the same device, but found
> at least two devices, cpu and cuda:0! (when checking argument for
> argument mat1 in method wrapper_addmm)

So, I am trying to check which device the tensors are loaded on, and when I run `data.x.get_device()` and `data.edge_index.get_device()`, I get `-1` for each. What does -1 mean?

In general, I am a bit confused as to when I need to transfer data to the device (whether cpu or gpu), but I assume for each epoch, I simply use .to(device) on my tensors to add to the proper device (but as of now I am not using .to(device) since I am just testing with cpu).

**Additional context:**

I am running ubuntu 20, and I didn't see this issue until installing cuda (i.e., I was able to train/test the model on cpu but only having this issue after installing cuda and updating nvidia drivers).
I have `cuda 11.7` installed on my system with an nvidia driver compatible up to cuda 12 (e.g., cuda 12 is listed with `nvidia-smi`), and the output of `torch.version.cuda` is `11.7`. Regardless, I am simply trying to use the cpu at the moment, but will use the gpu once this device issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

#### It means the data is still on the CPU

-1 indicates not on any *GPU* device.

#### To move it to the GPU, use `.to()`

```
data.x = data.x.to(device)
data.edge_index = data.edge_index.to(device)
```

Answer (score 0):

-1 means the tensors are on CPU. when you do `.to(device)`, what is your `device` variable initialized as? If you want to use only CPU, I suggest initializing device as `device = torch.device("cpu")` and running your python code with `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES='' python your_code.py ...`

Typically, if you are passing your tensors to a model, PyTorch expects your tensors to be on the same device as your model. If you are passing multiple tensors to a method, such as your loss function ``nn.CrossEntropy()```, PyTorch expects both your tensors (predictions and labels) to be on the same device.

Comment: Hm. Thanks for the details! I find it strange I am getting the runtime error (mentioned in op) since -1 means cpu because I am not currently using .to(device) anywhere in my code. I did try using `torch.device('cpu')`, but I still receive the error.

Comment: Can you post some corresponding code snippet for this?